# How to get the number of identical rows?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table in SQL format with 3 columns and 1000 rows as per the below:

```
Name    Age
Nick    20
Msh     23
Kij     19
jkh     20
kjh     22
cbc     23
iuy     27
jhjh    19
```

I would like to see which names are in the same age and how many?

Comment: Are you using an ORM to talk to mysql?

Comment: No- I am using mySQLdb in Python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's more a SQL issue than a python issue.

You have to do use an aggregation function (count)

Try this query:

```
select name, count(*) as age from table
group by age;
```